# How can I fix ORA: 01013 (user requested cancel...) when trying to link Oracle tables in MS Access?

Tags: oracle, odbc, office365, ado, dao

I have installed Oracle Express (XE, version 18) on a Windows 10 (64-bit) machine with Office 365 (32-bit) installed.  I have installed the correct Oracle Instant Client (18_3) and its ODBC package (32-bit versions).  I successfully created a DSN using the ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit) tool in windows.

When I attempt to link tables into an Access database, I get error ORA:  01013. If I remove the timeout from the DSN configuration, it simply spins with the Oracle RDBMS kernel eating up CPU cycles for as long as I'm willing to sit and wait.

I have to be missing a configuration parameter somewhere on either the Oracle side or the Microsoft side, or I'm missing a Microsoft component. MS Visual Studio C++ redestributables for 2010, 2013, and 2017 are already present and Microsoft updates indicates that my .NET framework is up to date.

I have attempted this same task with Oracle 12c and instant clients 12_1 and 12_2.  In both cases, the behavior is the same.

Any and all ideas sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Upon further testing, the DSN works correctly with ActiveX Data Objects.  I think that rules out the ODBC driver as the problem or any MS components required to allow it to function correctly.  I suspect that the problem lies with Access for Office 365.

Comment: To simplify the configuration, you can upgrade office 365 32 bits to 64 bits. Then you will not need to install 32-bit instant client. Then you will have a homogeneous 64 bit environment 18c 64 bit, ODBC 64 bit, office 365 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish I could solve it that easily, but a student of mine discovered the problem and I cannot force him to upgrade to the 64-bit version, as it is not completely tested with all add-ins.  I can recreate the same problem on a laptop with the same OS and version of Office 365.  Mine is a clean install (brand new laptop), so it's not some other package creating a conflict.

Comment: I opened a support ticket with the MIcrosoft Office team.  A technician spent about an hour remotely controlling my machine in an attempt to diagnose and solve the problem.  His efforts were unsuccessful and the issue has been escalated to the MIcrosoft Windows team for further exploration.

Comment: The Microsoft Windows team (once I figured out how to properly contact them) promptly referred the problem back to the Office team.  Gotta love MIcrosoft.

Comment: I also upgraded to the 64-bit version of Office 365.  The issue is unresolved with a homogeneous environment.

Comment: I performed two additional tests.  Microsoft Power BI is able to establish a connection, query the database, and return data.  I cobbled together a test in VBA as well using DAO.  I was able to open the database using DAO, but any attempt to open a recordset or access the tabledefs collection fails on the database with error 3146 -- ODBC Call Failed.  That behavior is consistent with what I see in Access when I attempt to link tables.

Comment: Cross referencing the diagnosis thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55988185/is-this-a-microsoft-or-an-oracle-problem